# Round up/off to nearest 5

Tags: vim, numbers, rounding

I'm trying to round up a list of numbers to the nearest 5 and nearest 10.

example:

```
1562
1706
1665
1378
1439
```

I created this code to round up/off to nearest 5:

```
:exe "%s/\\d\\d\\d\\d/\\=substitute(submatch(0).'\\.0', '.*', (round(submatch(0)/5)*5), 'g')/g"
```

In the first part of the substitution I want to make a float from the submatch value adding `.0` to the submatch value.

Expected result:

```
1560
1705
1665
1380
1440
```

However, it gives a trailing character error.
What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `/` is present in the replacement string as the division operator, you need to use another delimiter character for the `:s` command. As per [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute), this can be any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric character, '\', '"'' or '|'.

To round a number `n` to the nearest multiple of `k` you can do:

```
(n + k/2) / k * k
```

Putting this all together, the command can be:

```
:%s!\v\d{4}!\=(submatch(0) + 2) / 5 * 5!
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know what would be the formula if I only want to `round up` or only want to `round off` to nearest 5? I'm trying and trying but cannot find the right formula.

Comment: @Reman: you can try `(n + (k-1))/k*k` for rounding up, and `n/k*k` for rounding down.